# Solve the differential equation $(D^3-3D^2+4D-2)y = (e^x +\cos x)$, where $D = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-operators

> Solve the differential equation $$(D^3-3D^2+4D-2)y = (e^x +\cos x)\,,$$ where $D = \dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$.

Here, for $e^x$, we place coefficient of $x$ in place of $D$ which is $1$ but $D=1$ is solution for given equation. So how to solve this for particular integral?

Comment: Use latex please

Comment: Hint: Factorize $D^3-3D^2+4D-2$

Comment: @Koro  I think that is not what the OP asked for.  Since the OP knows "$D=1$ is a solution" (although I find this phrase a bit problematic), I think the OP knows that factorization of the characteristic polynomial $\lambda^3-3\lambda^2+4\lambda-2$ is required.  The OP knows that since $\lambda=1$ is a root, and we also have an $\exp(x)$-term on the right-side of the equation, so the question is: how to deal with the situation.

Comment: **Hint.**  Make an Ansatz that a particular solution is given by $$y_p(x)=Ax\exp(x)+B\cos(x)+C\sin(x)$$ for some constants $A$, $B$, and $C$.  The term $Ax\exp(x)$ comes from the fact that $\lambda=1$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial of the differential equation, so it is not enough to just use $A\exp(x)$ in a particular solution.  Hence, you need an extra factor of $x$: $A{\color{red}x}\exp(x)$.

Comment: @user10354138  I am not complaining.  However, I am curious.  I noticed many people changed `\text{_}` to `\mathrm{_}` or `\operatorname{_}`.  In certain situations, I understand (e.g., if `\operatorname{_}` is used, the spacing is better than `\text{_}`).  However, I don't see the difference between `\text{_}` and `\mathrm{_}`.  Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Batominovski: It is sematic on this site, but more generally in TeX it does matter in terms of functionality.  `\text{}` is for text, `\mathrm{}` is for mathematical symbols just needed to be in roman typestyle.  `\operatorname{}` is only needed if there are no builtin operator (so `cos` should be `\cos` not `\operatorname{cos}` because it is superfluous).  See [this TeX stackexchange question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19502), for example.

Answer (score 2):

$$(D^3-3D^2+4D-2)y = \cos x$$
For this particular integral:
$$y_p =\dfrac 1 {(D^3-3D^2+4D-2)} \cos x$$
$$y_p =\dfrac 1 {3D+1} \cos x$$
$$y_p =\dfrac {3D-1} {9D^2-1} \cos x$$
$$-10y_p = ({3D-1})  \cos x$$
$$-10y_p =-3\sin x   -\cos x$$
$$y_p =\dfrac {3\sin x   +\cos x}{10}$$

---

$$(D^3-3D^2+4D-2)y = e^x$$
For this particular integral:
$$y_p =\dfrac 1 {(D-1)(D^2-2D+2)}e^x$$
$$y_p =\dfrac 1 {(D-1)}e^x=e^x\dfrac 1 {D}1$$
$$ \implies y_p =xe^x$$

---

Finally the particular integral  is:
$$\boxed {y_p =\dfrac {3\sin x   +\cos x}{10}+xe^x}$$

Comment: I have never seen this method of putting the differential operator $D$ in the denominator, can you give some references? Thank you

Comment: @enzotib It's called method of inverse operator  https://www.efunda.com/math/ode/linearode_invoperator.cfm  You can also find many answers to ode questions with this kind of solutions method  from members on MathStack.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30020/inverse-operator-methods-for-differential-equations

Comment: @enzotib You have also these MIT notes M.I.T. On page 2 and 3 it explaines some rules for operator  18.03Ordinary Differential EquationsNotes and Exercises https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwim4P3Fv97qAhXM26QKHdE5D2kQFjAGegQIAhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmath.mit.edu%2F~jorloff%2Fsuppnotes%2Fsuppnotes03%2F1803SupplementaryNotes_full.pdf&usg=AOvVaw15QlxdLdyuviF1Rt9aqAuY

Comment: Very good, thank you

Comment: You're welcome. @enzotib ,  Page 27 on MIT notes they present some rules of operator merhod.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative method, you could find the particular integral through the [method of undetermined coefficients](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/undeterminedcoefficients.aspx).

$$(D^3-3D^2+4D-2)y = e^x +\cos x$$
$$y'''-3y''+4y'-2y = e^x +\cos x$$

**Complementary Solution:**

$$y'''-3y''+4y'-2y=0$$
The characteristic equation for this differential equation and its roots are:
\begin{align}r^3-3r^2+4r-2&=(r - 1) (r^2 - 2 r + 2)\\&= 
(r-1)(r-(1+i))(r-(1-i))\\&=0
\end{align}
which implies that
$$r_1=1,~r_2=1+i,~r_3=1-i$$

The complementary solution is then
$$y_c=c_1e^x+c_2e^{x}\sin x+c_3e^x\cos x$$

**Particular Solution:**

We apply the method of undetermined coefficients. As the right-hand side is of the form $e^x +\cos x$, a reasonable guess would be $y_p=Ae^x+B\sin x + C\cos x$. However, $e^x$ is already part of the complementary solution, so we instead make the guess

$$y_p=Axe^x+B\sin x + C\cos x$$

Differentiating thrice we find

$$y'_p=Ae^x(x+1)-C\sin x+B\cos x$$
$$y''_p=Ae^x(x+2)-B\sin x-C\cos x$$
$$y'''_p=Ae^x(x+3)+C\sin x-B\cos x$$

Therefore

$$y'''_p-3y''_p+4y'_p-2y_p =Ae^x+(B-3C)\sin x+(3B+C)\cos x=e^x+\cos x$$

$$\begin{cases} 
          A=1\\
          B-3C=0 \\
          3B+C=1 
       \end{cases}\implies B=\frac{3}{10},~ C=\frac{1}{10}$$

Thus, the particular solution takes the form

$$y_p=xe^x+\frac{3}{10}\sin x + \frac{1}{10}\cos x$$